# I'm having trouble with libmysql on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, libmysql

I have a service, which runs fine under debian 8 (jessie). Now I would like to run it on a ubuntu 18.04 machine.
But when I start the service, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: how did you install mysql ?

Comment: apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev => libmysqlclient20

Comment: Check if you can find a libmysql version 18. Maybe you need to check on older version and install it manually.